# Why does a HttpRequest crashes my game after called the method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httprequest

Everytime i call this method from other classes it crashes my unity project.

Thanks for your help!
If tried the UnityWebRequests but its not what i need because i need to return the information to the caller of the method

This is the code i used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

using UnityEngine;

public class onlineApiInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    
    


    public string getInfo(string URL) {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string info = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this will freeze your method until it is done ... in general you should rather use a [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) and well not return the result to the caller of the method ;)

Comment: Or in other words `i need to return the information to the caller of the method` .. **why?**

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to find a way to make that work

Comment: Are you by any chance calling `getInfo()` from a method initiated by `StartCoroutine` unguarded from `Update()`?

Comment: No, im just calling the method from ```Update```

Comment: @DitIsMick well that's what MickyD ment ... you are every frame freezing until the method (= the request) is finished! You will want to at least wait until one is done before starting the next one and in the meantime continue your frames => do the request asynchronous

Comment: Thanks! I dont really understand what the asynchronous is but ill do some research